Is there a website that can locate the nearest triangle center from a point?
In this question, I conjecture that the sequence of points will converge

Given $A_1= (0,0), \ B_1=(11,2), \ C_1(3,5)$
, $C_{25}(3.3556952569262, 2.9821465573228)$ which should be very close to the point of convergence
when $A_1= (0,0), \ B_1=(9,4), \ C_1(0.8,2.5)$, $C_{25}=(1.4967360874863,1.3378128809702)$
I want to know the closest triangle center to this this point I randomly tried about 20 of the $72000$ triangle centers to see if one of them will be the points of convergence but non of these points was close enough to even consider them and I wonder if there is a way to locate the nearest one of them to $C_{25}$. Of course I can't try to brute force 72000 points by constructing each of them so my question is:  Is there a website that can locate the nearest triangle center from a point ?

In the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers, there's a lookup feature. (It's under "Tables/Search 6,9,13".) To use it, you calculate the trilinear (or barycentric) coordinates of your point in a $6$-$9$-$13$ host triangle, and an associated numerical value that you can check against a list. If you find the value, then you've found the corresponding center. If not, then you might just have defined a new center.

@Blue What is "a 6
-9
-13
host triangle"?

A "$6$-$9$-$13$ host triangle" is a triangle with side-lengths $6$, $9$, $13$ on which you perform your construction. :)  So, put your initial coordinates at, say, $A_1=(0,0)$, $B_1=(13,0)$, and $C_1=(4.7692\ldots,3.6406\ldots)$, run your construction algorithm to get your proposed point of convergence. Then determine the trilinear/barycentric coordinates of that point and follow the ETC's lookup instructions. (I think the process could be significantly streamlined, but it is what it is.)

If I understood the instructions correctly, all I need to know to is to draw that $6-9-13$ triangle where $AB=13$ and $BC=6$ then I need to find the distance between my point and $BC$ and compare it with the table ?
I am just making sure that I did everything correct because that point that I am looking for is not in the list

"I need to find the distance between my point and $BC$" ... More-precisely: the signed distance (positive inside the triangle; negative outside). ... These kinds of dynamical systems aren't my thing, but I'd be surprised if there were a "closed form" representation of this pt. Still pretty nifty, though! :) ... ETC seems interested in pts with explicit formulas, but you could always contact the Keeper (see the Links page) and suggest a companion catalogue of iteratively-defined pts (as has been done with bicentric pairs).
